Curved arrows from tikz-cd do not work
I'm using Quiver and I have troubles making diagrams with curved arrows. For instance, it proposes me to put this is my document :
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2.25em]
    A \& B
    \arrow[curve={height=-12pt}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

but, it does not compile. TexMaker tells me : Package tikz Error: + or - expected, and Use of \tikz@curveCdot doesn't match its definition.
I use both tikz and tikz-cd in my preamble.
MWE :
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% A TikZ style for curved arrows of a fixed height, due to AndréC.
\tikzset{curve/.style={settings={#1},to path={(\tikztostart)
    .. controls ($(\tikztostart)!\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    and ($(\tikztostart)!1-\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
    .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    settings/.code={\tikzset{quiver/.cd,#1}
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/quiver/##1}}},
    quiver/.cd,pos/.initial=0.35,height/.initial=0}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \& B
    \arrow[curve={height=-12pt}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Here there is the solution: https://foro.rinconmatematico.com/index.php?topic=122255.0. You should put a complete code and not a fragment and remember that Quiver is only a tool. Use bend left o right like as documentation of tikz-cd.

Thanks for your interest. I am aware of that topic but it didn't work. I've edited my question with a full code.

Your complete code is the same copy of my link (in the preamble to found the solution). Impossible totally that the solution of your problem didn't work! It worlks. Your question moreover is actually in contraddition.

No, it doesn't work. The problem comes from the \usepackage[french,english]{babel} line. I'm coming to this place to know why. Saying "use bend" is not an answer because, like I utterly explained, I know 'bend' works, and I've said in the very title of the question that I've came to make 'curve' work.

Why your code works in my laptop? Also if I use or not use in the preamble\usetikzlibrary{babel}.

It worked! I just added that to my MWE and it seems to have solved everything. As for the rest, maybe the difference in our results is due to the french language option.

You're forgetting to load the babel library.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,babel} % <--- IMPORTANT!

% A TikZ style for curved arrows of a fixed height, due to AndréC.
\tikzset{
  curve/.style={
    settings={#1},
    to path={
      (\tikztostart)
      .. controls ($(\tikztostart)!\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
      and ($(\tikztostart)!1-\pv{pos}!(\tikztotarget)!\pv{height}!270:(\tikztotarget)$)
      .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes
    },
  },
  settings/.code={%
    \tikzset{quiver/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/quiver/##1}}%
  },
  quiver/.cd,
  pos/.initial=0.35,
  height/.initial=0,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \& B
    \arrow[curve={height=-12pt}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A & B
    \arrow[curve={height=-12pt}, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}

No need for ampersand replacement.


I don't know the option curve, but why don't you use a simple bend (left or right)?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2.25em]
    A \& B
    \arrow[bend right, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}



Thanks for your answer. I usually don't use bend, because the 'curve' parameter given by Quiver allows me to configure the curve itself. It is also possible with bend, so I agree, it is an option. It's just sad that I have to dig into Quiver results, especially when I have consequent diagrams to make... So I'm still trying to make the solution above work.

@LouisLascaud Sorry, I don't know Quiver.

@CarLaTeX Quiver is a tool/editor WYSIWYG on line to make commutative diagrams with tikz-cd: https://q.uiver.app/ I have written in my previous comment to use  bend left o right.
